# IODisplayConnect is gone in Big Sur of Apple Silicon, what is the replacement?

Tags: macos

I have two Big Sur laptops, one is Intel and other is M1(MacBook Pro M1), when I run command "ioreg | grep -i iodisplayconnect", the Intel one still has it, but M1 system found nothing, anyone know its replacement in M1 Big Sur? I need it to detect display names

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, but I was looking for IODisplayConnect for the purposes of reading the display brightness.

On a M1 Mac with Big Sur, I found the easiest way to **get** the brightness info is by running `corebrightnessdiag`:

```
$ /usr/libexec/corebrightnessdiag status-info | grep 'DisplayServicesBrightness '
                DisplayServicesBrightness = "0.9302966";
```

To **get and set** brightness from code, you can use private APIs from the DisplayServices framework (`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DisplayServices.framework`):

```
extern int DisplayServicesGetBrightness(int display, float *brightness);
extern int DisplayServicesSetBrightness(int display, float brightness);

// Change brightness
float brightness = 0.8;
int err = DisplayServicesSetBrightness(1, brightness);

// Get current brightness
err = DisplayServicesGetBrightness(1, &brightness);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use DisplayServices in swift?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NSScreen is the answer, not perfect since couldn't get other informaiton